# How to switch from one project to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications

Have two `asp.net` web form project,they share same `database` for some reason need to create two project.Now problem is can not switch from one project to another.

Suppose my project names are Pro1 and Pro2. All are active but how to brows from Pro1 to Pro2.

Comment: you can write the url for your project in the web browser to open the project. You can set multiple projects to run in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project you want run in solution explorer and select "Set as Start Project".

If you want to build only a single project in your solution, then right click the project you do not want to build and click "Unload project". This will not remove the project from solution.

If you want to remove the project from solution, then right click the project and select remove.